# "I wish you wouldn't drink so much" vs. "I wish you didn't drink so much."

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Where is the difference in meaning of these two sentences?

"I wish you **wouldn't drink** so much" vs. "I wish you **didn't drink** so much."

Comment: The first is a suggestion, the second a lament.

Comment: Note that it's perfectly possible to say *I wish **I didn't** drink so much*, but it doesn't really make sense to say *I wish **I wouldn't** drink so much*. When you say *I wish **you wouldn't** do it*, you mean *I want you **not to want to** do it*. But when reflexively applied back to the *speaker*, it's a bit weird to be saying what amounts to *I want to not do what I want to do.*

Comment: @FF Jekyll & Hyde.